# JavaScript update value in mongodb atlas with axios not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I'm trying to update value in mongoDB and it's not changing the value. I checked the values and they are ok and I checked the errors and everything looks good. what am I missing?

**Mongo atlas**
[picture of my mongo values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMry5.png)

type: Number,

default: 0

**code :**

> ```
> // symbol = the symbol of the coin | ammount = the ammount of coin
> // in this case : symbol = USDT | ammount = 3
> ```

```
  const setCoin = async (symbol, ammount) => {
    setError(false);
    try {
      setError(false);
      const res = await axios.patch("http://localhost:3001/api/users/setCoin", {
        email: user.email,
        symbol, ammount
      });
      res.data && window.location.replace("/home");
      console.log(error)
    } catch (err) {
      setError(true);
    }
  };
```

**server side**

//setCoin

```
router.route("/setCoin")
  .patch(async (req, res,) => {
    try {
      const symbol = req.body.symbol;
      const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ "email": req.body.email }, { $set: { symbol: req.body.ammount } }, { upsert: true });
      console.log("succes to set coin");
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(User.symbol);
      console.log(err)
    }
  });
```

Comment: did you check the req body before update

Comment: yes . same as i expected symbol = USDT | ammount = 3

Comment: Console the user and check the response from db.

Comment: i have log and its getting the correct user but not changing the value   USDT: 0,

Answer (score 0):

So as I dont know how you defined your User model can you try the following:

```
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ "email": req.body.email }, { $set: { [symbol]: req.body.ammount } }, { upsert: true });
```

Comment: thanks man ! its work . did not notice that [] not there